# Magento 2: How to add attribute flag to quote item?

Tags: magento2, quote, quoteitem

I want to add an attribute to quote item to know if an item can be deleted or not from a cart. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out extension attributes, which is what I believe you are looking for. This blog article explains things pretty well:
https://store.fooman.co.nz/blog/an-introduction-to-extension-attributes.html